# Change or increase multiple CSS animation delay

Tags: css, animation

What's a good way to apply a change to animation delay across many set elements?
If so .element1,... .elementXX have all unique timings. Then you want to change all the delays by 5 extra seconds.

I could use a settimeout to apply an animation start class to the element, but is there should be a more efficient solution?

*Edit

For clarification. Existing animation

```
.element1{animation: fade 1s linear 1s normal;}
.element2{animation: fade 1s linear 2s normal;}
.element3{animation: fade 1s linear 3s normal;}
.
.
.
.elementXX{animation: fade 1s linear XXs normal;}
```

Considering that all these animation timings and delays are already set, can you set a delay that increases ontop the existing ones. +10secs etc...

Comment: Are you asking for complete things to do for you or you missing code parts to show as reference what you have done ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've updated my post. Hopefully it clarifies what I'm asking.